# chrome dev tool debugging browser version

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Can i change the version of browser while debugging.

I'm currently using chrome.

I want to test my application for chrome older version compatibility.

Is their any option using chrome dev tools to change chrome versions.

Comment: I think you can use Browser stack for the same it free for some time

Comment: Did you check it ..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Browser stack for the same it free for some time

[browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely no feature within Chrome DevTools to change Chrome versions.

Chrome doesn't provide a simple or official way to download old versions. You might be able to find some unofficial archives of old versions, but use with caution.

> Can I roll back Google Chrome to a previous version?
>
> No - rollback is not supported.
>
> To get to a previous version (which would not be supported by Google),
>   you would need to uninstall your current version, delete every user's
>   saved profile data, and re-install the older version.  Users' personal
>   profile data is kept in:
>
> On Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\\Local
>   Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data  On Windows Vista /
>   7: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/frequently-asked-questions